# Android webcam streaming

Tags: android, video, streaming

I found code of application, which (in theory) receives video stream and shows on VideoView object.

```
package com.example.cameraapp;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

public class Camera extends Activity {
public VideoView mVideoView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

    String LINK = "192.168.1.102:9889";
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
    mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
    mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
    Uri video = Uri.parse(LINK);
    videoView.setMediaController(mc);
    videoView.setVideoURI(video);
    videoView.start();


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_camera, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

However, when I run VLC player ->Stream -> Http port 9889 -> transcode MPEG-2 NO SOUND appears statement "Unfortunatelly, cannot display this video file".
I tried rtsp, transcode H.264, but it didn't help.
Anyone know why it's not working?